# Draw a line and curves with fading edges with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, qpainter

`QPainter` is very easy to use and to draw a line one would simply do this:

```
QPainter painter(&image);
QPen pen;
pen.setWidth(5);
pen.setColor("black");
painter.setPen(pen);
painter.drawLine(QPointF(0,0), QPointF(200,250));
```

Now this works well, but I would like to create a "special" pen that produce lines with "smoothed" edges. For example, suppose the line I want to draw has a thickness of 10 pixels, then I would like the middle of the line (by middle I mean in terms of thickness and not length) to be fully opaque and at the edges the line should become semitransparent. I believe this could be obtained for example having the picture below as my point and then "drag" and paint the line so I will obtain the effect I desire. I know that Qt provides you with `QBrush` and gradients, but I can't figure out how to to do this.

[image: Pic]

Comment: Does qt allow you to do per pixel manipulations? Can you set the value of an individual pixel to be an arbitrary color?

Comment: @Makogan yes it is possible to do that via this [QPainter::drawPoint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawPoint)

Comment: Ok, this is not an efficient way to go about this at all but depending on your requirements it may be good enough.

Take your line of 10 pixels let;s make 4 of those pixels fully opaque so you just draw a regular line with thickness 4.

Then you draw a line with thickness 1, parallel to the previous line, but offsetted by one pixel along the orthogonal direction of that line (direction vector rotated by 90 degrees)

You keep drawing these parallel lines, making them progressively transparent as you move away from the original line.

Comment: I you have access to shaders through QT, which I think it supports, you can create your own custom line shader to do this for you by drawing a rectangle rather than the default QT lines.

Comment: This does seem like an idea, but I am not sure about if the line would be antialiased

Comment: This is how antialiasing works however.

The proper line antialising algorithm on a shader is. You draw a rectangle, then you interpolate from opaqueness to transparency relative to the distance of the current rendered point to the line.

i.e you have a rectangle such that the mid line of that rectangle is the line you are trying to render. The transparency of a point on that rectangle is proportional to the distance to the line.

What I am unsure of is how much control QT gives you to manipulate it's shading pipeline.

Comment: The closest hting to that is the algorithm I gave you

Comment: @Makogan I have tried to implement something like this but there is a problem with it. It works for lines only, if you want to draw curves (sequence of lines), each line being different length, then basically the rectangles drawn do not form a continuous path as when the line are rotating the rectangle are also rotating (hence leaving some are "empty")

Comment: Assuming constant length lines, what you do is, at the tip of the rectangle you interpolate based on the distance to the tip point, rather than the distance to the line.

i,e you make a shorter line than the line you are drawing and pixels get darkend with respect ot the shortest distance to that segment (not the infinitline but the actual finite length segnment)

Comment: Essentially you want the 2D version of this:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Capsule_geometry.svg/1200px-Capsule_geometry.svg.png

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsule_(geometry)

Answer (score 3):

While Qt definitely has [many drawing functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/paintsystem.html), there is none to let you draw using a pixmap brush along a path like you describe.

I can think of 2 ways to achieve what you want:

1. Draw the path using standard non-fuzzy brush multiple times with a varying brush width and a transparent color. With enough iterations this will approximate the "fuzzy line" you are looking for.
2. Draw the pixmap repeatedly along the path. This is usually how drawing software like photoshop or gimp will do it as it allows for some flexibility in the parameters such as different brush pixmaps and orientations etc.

I will  try to provide example code (untested for now as I am currently away from my dev computer) for the second way of doing it here:

```
void drawPathWithPixmapBrush(QPainter painter, QPainterPath path, QPixmap pixmapBrush, qreal spacing=1.0) {
    qreal length = path.length();
    qreal pos = 0.0;
    // Adjust the spacing to be relative to brush size
    spacing=(spacing * pixmapBrush.width() );
    while (pos < length) {
        qreal percent = path.percentAtLength(pos);
painter.drawPixmap(path.pointAtPercent(percent), pixmapBrush);
pos += spacing;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this code will iteratively move along the given [QPainterPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html), and for each step draw the [QPixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) brush to the given [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html), resulting in what can be preceived as one continuous line drawn along the path with the pixmap brush.

QPainterPath supports all drawing operations that QPainter does, such as polygons, splines, lines, arches etc., so it will function as a dropin replacement for your existing QPainter draw calls for the most part (see [the full list of drawing operations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#public-functions)).

Here is example code to construct a simple straight line segment using `QPainterPath`:

```
QPainterPath path
QPointF lastPosition(10, 10);
QPointF currentPosition(100, 100);
path.moveTo(lastPosition);
path.lineTo(currentPosition);
```

Possible improvements include calculating spacing so that it ends exactly on the end of the line, and also maybe more correctly calculating the required number of draws will best give the impression of a line.

Comment: I have tried something like that. However, I encountered two issues with this: 1. when the curves are long, you have draw lots of points and the performance is not optimal (in my live drawing app there is a lot of lag) 2. It is hard to get the spacing right, I tried with `qreal spacing = brushSize/path.length()` but what I got worked for paths for certain lengths.

Comment: @daljit97: Unfortunately this is the reality of the beast. You may get better performance/and quality with the first method. I will see if I can write a pseudo code for it. The other option is to abandon Qt drawing primitives and the acceleration/performance they bring and just implement your own rendrer. But that is a whole other story.

Comment: yeah, the custom rendering would be overkill. I would be happy if I could get the curves nicely rendered. Although the performance is suboptimal, I can solve by letting the user draw a normal line in "live" mode and then redraw the curve with the desired effect. The real issue is my QPainterPath is composed of several lines of varying length and I cannot find an equation for the spacing that gives nice smooth lines for all lengths (if I use a spacing that is too small, the fading is invisible because of overlapping and if it's too large then the "balls" are spaced out and disconnected).

Comment: @daljit97 : If you think about it, the problem becomes one of selecting how many dots to draw. This will give you the opportunity to linearly trade performance for quality as more dots is slower and nicer, less dots is faster and uglier. One approach would be to adaptively select dot count based on last frame's rendering time. The other thing you need to figure out is the transparency to use when drawing pixmaps. You can calculate this using area of overlap for two adjacent circles (https://milania.de/blog/Intersection_area_of_two_circles_with_implementation_in_C%2B%2B)

Comment: I am not sure if changing the pixmap's transparency would solve it. Anyway, I have created a small [repository](https://github.com/daljit97/QtPaintTest) and using a `QRadialGradient` as suggested in the other answer. The effect is close to what I want, but the curves arent't exactly perfect.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to use a [QRadialGradient](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qradialgradient.html) as a brush for your QPen :

```
QPointF centerPoint(400, 400);
qreal centerRadius = 200;

QRadialGradient radialGrad(centerPoint, centerRadius);
radialGrad.setColorAt(0.000, QColor(0, 0, 0, 255));
radialGrad.setColorAt(0.8, QColor(0, 0, 0, 0.8 * 255));
radialGrad.setColorAt(1.000, QColor(0, 0, 0, 0.000));

QPen pen;
pen.setWidth(400);
pen.setColor("black");
pen.setBrush(radialGrad);

QPainter painter(this);
painter.setPen(pen);
painter.drawPoint(centerPoint);
```

[image: Gradient brush screenshot result]

The downside of this technique is the fact that the gradient is not smooth near the GradientStop. You should add several GradientStop to ease your radial gradient.

Another (and prettier) way to achieve this could be to create a custom QBrush with a dedicated texture or texture image (using the method [QBrush::setTexture](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qbrush.html#setTexture) or [QBrush::setTextureImage](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qbrush.html#setTextureImage)) representing the wanted brush pattern.

Comment: but can this be used for drawing curves? I have tried using bresenham algorithm but curve weren't continuous

Comment: Yep. With both techniques, you can spread those points along a line/curve with the right margin between them (depending on the size of your texture or point radius). Don't know the solution (if there is one) using directly the painter.drawLine(..) method.

Comment: I have tried to implement this [here](https://github.com/daljit97/QtPaintTest), however I still can't find a way to get the curves to be smooth.